# PickVisualMedia contract not showing all albums

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm facing a problem with the image picker on Jetpack compose, I have implemented it and when you launch the image picker it only shows some albums that the user has on the device but not all of them.

On this example it only shows the Favorite, Camera, Screenshots and Downloads, but it does not show for example the AdobeLightRoom, Whatsapp, etc...

[image: Example of how the picker dialog shows]

Do someone knows if this is a privacy limitation (I wouldn't understand because camera album it's more sensitive than AdobeLightroom for example) or some bug?
Here you have how I've implemented the picker:

```
val multiplePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(maxItems = MAX_IMAGES_SELECTED),
        onResult = { uris -> viewModel.updateSelectedImages(uris) })

multiplePhotoPickerLauncher.launch(
                            PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly)
                        )
```

This are the paths of the albums that are showing and also ones that not:
**SHOWING**

```
/Storage/DCIM/Download
/Storage/DCIM/Camera
/Storage/DCIM/Screenshots
```

**NOT SHOWING**

```
/Storage/DCIM/Sunsets
/Storage/DCIM/PhotosEditor
/Storage/Pictures/AdobeLightroom
/Storage/Pictures/Instagram
```

Thank you very much!!

Comment: Yes PickVisualMedia() does not let you pick from other folders. This has been reported before. Its a terrible new feature. It has other drawbacks too. It will often show images from those folders under Recent. But also terrible to scroll for an image.

Comment: @blackapps actually for me all the albums are shown but not by default, when i open the image picker by default it shows **recent** but if i click on the menu button up left it shows me a bunch of options one of them is Gallery if I click it now i have access to all images and albums or at least this is the case for my xiaomi Redmi phone

Comment: @blackapps has it been reported to Android? I think it's a terrible bug that should be fixed... Anyway, really appreciate the info!

Comment: I never saw a menu here. So that will be device specific. But if you can reach all folders then what is the complaint?

Comment: @blackapps in my case i can't reach all the folders, only the recent/default one's that shows the screenshot I've posted. If I want for example to post an image of AdobeLightroom i have to go first to the image from device gallery, mark it like favorite and then select this image on favorite folder.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I am also facing 100% same issue using new media picker. Any updates here?

Comment: Now I'm wondering this is whether concept or bug.