# How to enable Browse option in Photo Picker Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-photo-picker

When I implement a Photo Picker functionality in my app using [Photo Picker Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/photopicker) library. I have access only Camera, Screenshot and Download folders including some recent photos/videos, Not the complete access. But in one of the google implemented app ([Snapseed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed&hl=en&gl=US)), Same kind of photo picker can access the [Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Storage) picker to acess other directories after clicking on browse button. For reference I have attached a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWkkh.jpg)

Can anyone please help me, how to achieve the browse button in native android photo picker?

Comment: You have not even mentioned PickVisualMedia() contract. Nor posted your code. Nor mentioned menu.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77280010/pickvisualmedia-contract-not-showing-all-albums

Comment: Please tell why you think that menu leads to ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Why not ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT? Does that menu contain more options? Screenshot?

Comment: I now see in the Android docs you linked that the menu dots are there in the examples. But i have never seen them.

Comment: @blackapps I have added photo picker android reference which is very simple to implement, and about ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, I think it is use to open a document throught native intent, GET_CONTENT is use to pick file/content.

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.niksoftware.snapseed&hl=en&gl=US Did you try this app? Have a look on this triple dot (menu) button, which i have aaded in the screenshot in the question itself.

Comment: Why should i try that app? I would not know if it used PickVisualMedia() contract to begin with. I have never seen these menu dots i already told. Please post your code. Dont let us guess what you did. You are still not mentioning PickVisualMedia() contract. Any reason? You also did not tell why you think that it has anything to do with ACTION_GET_CONTENT. Also you did not post a screenschot of the expanded menu which you call a browse button. Strange.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. This support article seems to say some apps don't "allow you to browse" but I can't find anything about how to allow or not allow: https://support.google.com/android/answer/13356023?hl=en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the "Browse" option by using `ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()` instead of `ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()`. What this is effectively doing is creating the following Intent:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
                .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                .setType("image/*")
```

I believe you can launch that intent directly or my code is using the ActivityResultContracts paradigm inside of a composable so it looks like this:

```
val photoPickerLauncher =
       rememberLauncherForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri ->
            //do something with image uri
        }

photoPickerLauncher.launch(MIME_TYPE_IMAGE)
```

Previously I was using `ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia()` as outlined in the docs. With that, I wasn't getting the browse option on the photo picker. With the code above, I do. I also tested on an Android 11 device and it works fine using the old gallery UI.

Now I can't really explain why this works so use at your own risk. I find documentation for PhotoPicker and Gallery selection in general very poor. But this seemed to work for me.

Comment: Thanks @Jacosta for this ultimate solution, and I think that this is happening because Android system changes its file management system for an app, If any application having read permission then it can access its own space (Android/media/PACKAGE_NAME) + public directories like (camera, downloads, screenshot). I also don't found any documentation regarding this but It can be the reason.